# What does it mean for a variable to disappear in a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have this matrix:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & -1 &|& 2 \\
2 & 6 & -1 & -6 &|& 1 \\
1 & 3 & 1 & 3 &|& 5 
\end{matrix}

Through row operations, we obtain the matrix

\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & -1 &|& 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4 &|& 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &|& 0 
\end{matrix}

so $x_1 = 2-3x_2+x_4$, $x_2$ is free, $x_3 = 3-4x_4$, $x_4$ is free.

We know this is an equivalent system because I performed valid algebraic operations on this system, and we have values for all variables, and there's no intermingling: $x_1$ is a function of strictly $x_2,x_4$, and $x_3$ is strictly a function of $x_4$. This makes complete sense and I typically am just like: "Ok, good, let's move on." But after staring at this perhaps longer than I should have, I was wondering why we know for a fact that this system must have 2 free variables: i.e. is it possible to express all variables in terms of one variable? For example, can $x_2$ be a function of $x_4$. When I stare at my solution, I think "obviously not: the $x_2$ magically disappears and thus cannot have any constraints" - I guess I'm wondering why this works and what this means.

Edit: After reading my post, I realize it may come across as confused ... I think I'm basically trying to shed light on a process that's been drilled into my head - produce leading one, clean columns, express basic variables in terms of free variables, and bam that's the answer - without me actually thinking of what's going on. I think the point is that what we have is an algebraically *equivalent* system, and so it just must work, and there must be two free variables because that's just how the algebra worked out - I guess I want some more light on what "it's just how the algebra worked out" means, if that's possible?

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rref}{rref}$The linear relationships you see between the columns of $A$ are exactly the same relationships between the columns of $\rref(A)$.

In $A$, the second column is 3 times the first. In $\rref(A)$ the second column is 3 times the first.

In $A$, the fourth column is 4 times the third minus the first. Same for $\rref(A)$. The only difference is that it is easier to see this for $\rref(A)$.

Given a list of vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots, v_m$, we can form the matrix $\rref(v_1,\dots,v_m)$ by asking a sequence of questions:

1. is $v_1 = 0$? If so, then the first column of $\rref(v_1,\dots,v_m)$ is $0$, otherwise it's $(1,0,0,\dots,0)^\top$.
2. is $v_2 = a v_1$ for some $a$? If so then the second column of $\rref(v_1,\dots,v_m)$ is $(a,0,0,\dots,0)^\top$, otherwise it's your second pivot, $(0,1,0,0,\dots)^\top$.

If the $i$-th column is a pivot, let us call $v_i$ a pivot vector.

3. is $v_3$ a linear combination of the pivot vectors among $v_1, v_2$? E.g. if $v_3 = av_1 + bv_2$ then the third column is $(a,b,0,0,\dots,0)^\top$. Otherwise $v_3$ is the next pivot vector.

and just continue like this

4. is $v_{k + 1}$ a linear combination of the pivot vectors among $v_1,\dots,v_k$? E.g. if the pivot vectors are $v_3, v_4, v_6, v_7$ and $v_8 = 2v_3 + 0v_4 + v_6 - 4v_7$ then the $8$-th column becomes $(2,0,1,-4,0,0,0,\dots)^\top$. Otherwise $v_{k+1}$ is the next pivot vector.

---

Let $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$ be the columns of your first matrix—including the last column. Then

- $v_1 \neq 0$ so it's a pivot:

\begin{pmatrix} 1 &&&& \\ 0 &&&& \\ 0 &&&& \end{pmatrix}

- $v_2 = 3v_1$:

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 &&& \\ 0 & 0 &&& \\ 0 & 0 &&& \end{pmatrix}

- $v_3$ is not a scalar multiple of the pivot vector $v_1$, so $v_3$ is the next pivot vector:

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 && \\ 0 & 0 & 1 && \\ 0 & 0 & 0 && \end{pmatrix}

- the pivot vectors are $v_1, v_3$ and $v_4 = -v_1 + 4v_3$:

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 & -1 & \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& \end{pmatrix}

- the pivot vectors are still $v_1, v_3$ and $v_5 = 2v_1 + 3v_3$:

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

The pivot vectors are linearly independent, and every column is either a pivot vector or a linear combination of pivot vectors. I.e. the pivot vectors form a basis (spanning + linearly independent) for the column space.

Which vectors are free and which are pivots depends on the order of your columns. If we swap $v_1$ and $v_2$ then $v_2$—which now comes first—is a pivot vector and $v_1 = \frac13 v_2$ is no longer a pivot because it comes after $v_2$ in the list. So if you swap the vectors around you can get a different basis. But, remember that different basis for the same space have the same number of vectors. You cannot have 2 pivot vectors in one basis and 3 pivot vectors in another.

Another way to look at it is as a parameterized set. You have pivot variables $x_1$ and $x_3$ which are linear functions of your two free variables $x_2$ and $x_4$—and also $x_2$ and $x_4$ are functions of $x_2$ and $x_4$. So your solution set is parameterized by these functions $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. So the solution set is

$$\{f(x_2, x_4) = (2-3x_2+x_4, x_2, 3-4x_4, x_4) : (x_2, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$$

Thus the solution set is the image of some function in two variables. It must be a plane. If there is only one variable, the image cannot be a plane because you cannot have a linear function in one variable hit every point in a plane. Functions in one variable give you lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 columns, i.e. 4 unknown variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. After performing row operations you see that only $2$ non-zero rows remained in the matrix, the matrix has rank $2$, i.e. you have $2$ independent conditions only. I.e. $4-2= 2$ free parameters have to be introduced, for example $x_2=a,x_4=b$. Unknown values of $x_1,~x_3$ can be determined as a function of these parameters, because the remaining matrix is regular.

\begin{align}
x_1&=2-3x_2+x_4=2-3a+b,\\
x_3&=3-4x_4=3-4b.
\end{align}

All together:

\begin{align}
x_1&=2-3a+b,\\
x_2&=a,\\
x_3&=3-4b,\\
x_4&=b.\\
\end{align}

where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.