# Qualms about elementary algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$2 + 2p \geq 0$ and $2-2p \geq 0$

I know $2p \geq -2$ and $2 \geq 2p$ and so we get $1 \geq p \geq -1$.

Why does the following method not work?

Why can't you subtract $2 - 2p \geq 0$ on both sides of $2 + 2p \geq 0$ to get $ 4p \geq 0$ and so $p \geq 0$?

I don't see any faults in algebraic manipulation.

Also, this is the type of problem that makes me feel seriously anxious when it comes to basic algebraic manipulations. I don't see the difference between the second approach above (subtracting/adding equations together) and Gaussian Elimination. I expressed this concern of losing/gaining solutions to a system of equations in

[What does it mean for a variable to disappear in a linear system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360260/what-does-it-mean-for-a-variable-to-disappear-in-a-linear-system)

post.

Also, I think I absorbed both equations into the same one by adding the equations with each other, like how when you add two linear equations, you "absorb" the constraints.

Comment: rules for combining inequalities are not all the same as rules for combining equalities

Comment: you are proceding as if $a \geqslant b$ and $c \geqslant d$ implies $a - c \geqslant b - d$, so you should think about why that isn't true

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274932

Comment: Say $p = - 0.5$. Is $2+2p \gt 2-2p$? No. Subtracting $(2-2p)$ on both sides gives $4p \lt 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, for instance, $1\geqslant0$ and $3\geqslant0$, but it doesn't follow from this that $-2(=1-3)\geqslant0$.

Comment: Wow my bad. Thank you.